# Factorial running time

Tags: python, time-complexity

When analyzing some code I've written, I've come up with the following recursive equation for its running time -

T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n! + O(n^2).

Initially, I assumed that O((n+1)!) = O(n!), and therefore I solved the equation like this -

T(n) = n! + O(n!) + O(n^3) = O(n!)

Reasoning that even had every recursion yielded another n! (instead of (n-1)!, (n-2)! etc.), it would still only come up to n*n! = (n+1)! = O(n!). The last argument is due to sum of squares.

But, after thinking about it some more, I'm not sure my assumption that O((n+1)!) = O(n!) is correct, in fact, I'm pretty sure it isn't.

If I am right in thinking I made a wrong assumption, I'm not really sure how to actually solve the above recursive equation, since there is no formula for the sum of factorials...

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you measuring the time of a factorial algorithm or is this the result of your measurement of some other function?

Comment: The function I wrote is intended to receive a list and output a list containing all of its permutations. It's used for calculating the determinant of a matrix. Basically, the function runs over every member of the list (n in total) and for each it creates a sub-list not containing that member (O(n)), calculates all the permutations of the sub-list (T(n-1)) and then goes over every such permutation, appending to each the number that was taken off ((n-1)!). All in all I get the recursive equation I wrote earlier. Determinant calculations usually take O(n!), I also saw it mentioned on Wikipedia.

Comment: You can ignore the `O(n^2)` term, since `n! = O(n^n)` by Sterling's approximation.

Comment: Yes, I know, I wrote it there for completion's sake, it's not the issue. I just don't know how to solve the rest of it...

Comment: Also, `(n+1)!` is (more than) a factor of `n` greater than `n!`, so `(n+1)! = omega(n!)` (i.e., it grows strictly faster than `n!`).

Comment: Exactly, I thought as much, which means I don't know how to solve T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n!... For that I need to know the order of magnitude of the sum of factorials.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking at run-time, I assume `O(n^2)` is meant to be the number of operations on that term.  Under that assumption, `n!` can be computed in `O(n)` time (`1*2*3*...*n`).  So, it can be dropped in comparison to the `O(n^2)` term.  `T(n-1)` is then computed in approximately O((n-1)^2) time which is roughly O(n^2).  Putting it all together you have something which runs in

```
O(n^2) + O(n) + O(n^2)
```

resulting in an `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Comment: O(n^2) is meant here simply as Big-O notation, it can be replaced with simply "n^2" if it makes the calculation easier. The T(n-1) term is multiplied by n, though. If the equation were T(n) = n*T(n-1), the answer would surly be T(n) = n!. So how can it possibly be O(n^2) if I add more terms to the right side?

Comment: @Adam -- O(n^2) cannot be replaced by n^2 in Big-O notation.  n^2 takes 2 operations, not O(n^2) operations.  I think you might be confused by what Big-O means.  Big-O refers to the number of operations that it will take to complete a certain task -- It doesn't say anything about what the output of the task will be.  e.g. `n!` takes `n` operations.

Comment: In class, we use Big-O notation to indicate "Something that runs on the same order of magnitude as..." It is meant as a tight asymptotic bound.

Comment: @Adam -- You really need to tighten up your notation here.  `n!` is not the same as `O(n!)`.  If by `n!`, you meant `O(n!)`, then your algorithm scales so badly that it's not even worth trying to figure it out as you would probably have a hard time getting enough computer time to calculate the result with `n=10`.

Comment: It's meant to scale badly, the assignment was to build functions that calculate determinants, and they are meant to run quite slowly. I'm just having a hard time calculating just how slowly. I apologize for the sloppy notation, I'm still new at this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with:

```
 T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n! + O(n^2)
```

Is that you're mixing two different types of terms. Everything left of the final `+` refers to a number; to the right of that plus is `O(n^2)` which denotes the class of all functions which grow asymptotically no faster than `n^2`.

Assuming you mean:

```
T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n! + n^2
```

<strike>Then `T(n) in O(n!)` because `n!` is the fastest growing term in the sum. (Actually, I'm not sure that `n*T(n-1)` isn't faster growing - my combinatorics isn't that strong).</strike>

<strike>Expanding out the recursive term, the recursive "call" to `n*T(n-1)` reduces to some function which is <strike>`O((n!)!)`</strike> `O(n!)`, and so the function as a whole is `O(n!)`.</strike>

Fully expanding out the recursive term, it will be the fastest growing term. See the comments for various suggestions for the correct expansion.

Comment: I generally see the big-O notation to mean number of operations, not the asymptotic behavior ... Honestly, I don't think OP knows what he is talking about...

Comment: @mgilson That's certainly not how the notation is used in any text I'm aware of, and would indeed destroy it's meaning. If it denoted a number of operations, then a function with taking 2n^2 operations would not be O(n^2) because 2n^2 > n^2.

Comment: from your answer, it seems that O(n!) is the asymptotic behavior of the *function* (not the count of the number of operations) as `n!` can be computed in `O(n)` operations.  Of course you're correct that Big-O refers to the *asymptotic behavior of the number of operations*.

Comment: @mgilson I understand the function given to be a description of the number of operations required to perform the undisclosed underlying algorithm, and I think it is pretty clear that that is the basis of my answer.

Comment: Note that [`!!`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) is the wrong notation. Usually you define `n!! = 1 * 3 * 5 * 7 * ... * n` if `n` is odd and `n!! = 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 * ... * n` if `n` is even. You should write `O((n!)!)` to mean the factorial of `n!`.

Comment: Maybe you need parenthesis.

Comment: If you break down the recursive term, and ignoring the O(n^2) since it's much smaller, you get T(n) = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...1 + n! + (n-1)! + (n-2)! + ... + 1 = 2n! + (n-1)! + (n-2)! + ... + 1. This is a sum I simply do not know how to calculate...

Comment: @Adam [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k!%2C+k%3D1+to+n) says it's `-(-1)^nΓ(n+2)!(-n-2)-!(-1)-1` Where `Γ` is the gamma function, and `!n` is the [subfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n! + O(n^2) = n*T(n-1) + n! = n*( (n-1)T(n-2) + (n-1)! ) + n! = n(n-1)T(n-2) + 2n! = ... = n! = n*n! = O(n*n!)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the source code:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1982-L2032

it must be at most O(n) if not faster.